# Enter value from a cell into another based on conditions- across multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a row containing dates and a different row containing volumes.

In a separate cell I want to enter a date, it will check the date from the row I've mentioned and populate a blank cell with volume.

For example

IF Cell A= Cell B then populate Cell C with volume from Cell D
BUT if Cell A=Cell E then populate Cell C with volume from Cell F

Does this make sense?  Keep thinking it should be easier than I'm making it!

I just want to show what the results are depending on the date selection in a small summary table.

TIA, I'm totally stuck!

Comment: You might include in your post screenshots of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question (which is unclear and lacking an example of your data) you need a simple nested `IF` function.

In C2 use:

```
=IF(A2=B2,D2,IF(A2=E2,F2,""))
```